# Tabulator and tickcross header filter

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I have tickcross as header filter in some columns.
How to change all items in certain column to checked or unchecked at one click?
I cant find any example here: [tabulator](http://tabulator.info/)

Also I would like to know if it is possible
fit pagination info into screen when is used mobile phone with small screen width(360px).
here is screenshot:

[image]

Thank You so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Change All Items In Column At Once

To do this you would need to retrieve all rows using the ***getRows*** function and then use the ***update*** function on the row components to change the value.

It would also be worth using the ***blockRedraw*** and ***restoreRedraw*** functions to prevent redrawing of the table until all the rows were updated, as it will improve the efficiency of the operation

In the example below i will assume you are looking to update the `alarm` property of each row

```js
var rows = table.getRows();

table.blockRedraw(); //block table redrawing

//iterate over each row in the table
rows.forEach(function(row){
    row.update({alarm:true}); //set alarm to true
});

table.restoreRedraw(); //restore table redrawing
```

#### Wrap Pagination Element

To cause the pagination element to wrap you would need to use a bit of CSS, if you add it anywhere after you have imported the `tabulator.min.css` file

```css
.tabulator .tabulator-footer {
    white-space:normal;
}
```

Comment: Hi Oli, I spotted that undo function does not works when there are changed all columns at once.

Comment: function getHistoryUndoSize()  allway returns 0.

Comment: I forgot to say that there is the same behaviour at rowContextMenu & headerMenu too.= undo function does not works and function getHistoryUndoSize() allway returns 0.Can zou please help what I am doing wrong?

Comment: if you are having a separate issue please raise a separate question on stack overflow, it makes it much easier to provide a clean answer and helps other users find help faster

Comment: Hi Oli,I am sorry , I will create new question.Thank you